# How to disable all caching in Safari 13

Tags: caching, safari, browser-cache

When I toggle the disable resource cache in the network tab, the javascript and stylesheets are still loaded from `(memory)`.

I'm using webpack-dev-server (via vue-cli 3) which uses ETag headers, so Safari should send a `If-None-Match` requests, but doesn't.
As a workaround i'm using production mode which generates unique urls, but i'd rather use development mode.

Is there setting or special key-combo to **really** refresh the page?

Comment: Related (includes a workaround): https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than a year later, Safari still has the bug :-(

I did [find a key-combo sequence](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12049/how-to-clear-the-cache-or-do-a-hard-refresh-in-safari):

1. Clear the cache with: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
2. Refresh the page:  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

This is far from ideal and makes me wanting to avoid developing and testing in Safari.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. This helps take the edge off. I filed a bug report https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219323

Answer (score 3):

While you have the Web Inspector open, go to the "Network" tab.
Find the blue icon in the following photo:

[image: disable cache icon]

It should initially be initially grayed out, meaning that caching is enabled. Click on it to disable caching.

Comment: Yes, but does it work in for all resources in the latest safari? (Some resources were cached harder than others)

Comment: Nope, that icon still doesn't work. Just tested in Safari 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2) and the main.js was loaded from cache `(memory)`

Comment: As of Safari 15, the only way I can get this to work is using CMD + OPT + E before every refresh. The skip cache option in the network tab does not work when enabled. Safari sucks.